# how to access page variable in a custom.tag file?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, custom-tag

this is my custom tag file `css.tag`:

```
<%@ tag pageEncoding="UTF-8" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" body-content="empty" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ attribute name="value" %>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${cssdir}/${value}" />
```

whereas `${cssdir}` is a variable defined in `page.jsp`
i have found out that, `${cssdir}` is invisible in `css.tag`
How to solve this problem ?

Comment: On which scope id ${cssdir} defined  ?

Comment: @benjamin.d it is on page scope as designed

Comment: it would be rather easy if the var is is on application scope. but in my case, the variable is on page scope

Comment: This has got nothing to do with JSTL. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info to learn what JSTL actually is.

Answer (score 1):

The pageScope of your tag file, is not the same as your pageScope calling page. You have two options:

- Use a broader scope (request, session, application...)
- Define your cssdir as an attribute.

I'd go for the second option as this is cleaner. Your tagfile shouldn't know about the calling context.